# “example” heading in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been looking at ["example" heading in twitter bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404077/example-heading-in-twitter-bootstrap) but that's not what i wanted. 
What I would like to do is to change the content dynamically.

Regarding to this example http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/10/ i try to change `<div class="well example" style="">` to `<div class="well example" style="content:"dsd"">` but without success.

It's possible?? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Check out a quick non-hack workaround that I came up with here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15852394/2151817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't work, because it's the `:before` that holds the "Example" Text.

You can do it like this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/44/))

*HTML*

```
<div class="well example tree">Tree</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.tree:before { content: "Tree"; }
```